# How to change product name in quote item dynamically

Tags: event-observer, addtocart, attribute-set, quoteitem, sales-quote

Is it possible to add several the same product times to the cart with a different name? I did with different price, but I have not managed to do it with a different name.

I used an observer `"sales_quote_item_set_product"` but sets the same name when there are several products in cart.

The product is added by programming with `"checkout_cart_product_add_after"` event, using:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quoteItem = $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
$quoteItem->setProduct($product_model);
$quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
$quoteItem->setQty('1');
$quoteItem->setParentItem(NULL);
$quoteItem->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$quoteItem->setName('Custom Name')//I need this, but does not work
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
$quote->addItem($quoteItem)->save();
```

If I print the value of `$quoteItem` with `var_dump()` I see if the name was changed, but in the cart appears with the original name.

Another option was to use `$product_model->setName()` before `$quoteItem->setProduct($product_model)` but in the cart appears also  with the original name.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Magento change product name adding to cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684610/magento-change-product-name-adding-to-cart)

Use event `sales_quote_item_set_product`

```
class Mynamespace_Samples_Model_Observer
{
    public function salesQuoteItemSetProduct(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

        //only change the item you want by product id
        if($item->getProductId() == xyz){
            $item->setName('Ians custom product name');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: It update name of all the products in the cart and not the last product we added.

Comment: @ParthThummar even im facing same issue? were you able to solve the issue?