# Magento 2: change product name in quote item via event observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am trying to change the product name in the quote item via the **event observer**.

I followed this [guide](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104366/how-to-change-product-name-in-quote-item-dynamically) but it does not work.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 { 
     $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
     $item->setCustomPrice($price);
     $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
      $item->setName('New Name');
      $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
```

**The Event:**

> app/code/Test/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="dome_cart" instance="Test\Module\Observer\Option\AddCustomdOptionsToCart"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 2 set quote item name from `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item:setProduct`.

And the name set by your observer class is overridden by `setProduct`.

If you want to set your desire name for quote item then you have to

- use  after plugin on
  `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item:setProduct` .
- Or use observer on event `sales_quote_item_set_product`.

### Using Plugin

Create **di.xml** at `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/etc/` and defined plugin.

And **code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_Magento_Plugin_Magento_Quote_Model_Quote_Item" 
            sortOrder="10" type="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Quote\Model\Quote\Item"/>
</type>

</config>
```

## Declare the plugin class `Item.php` at `app\code\{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Quote\Model\Quote`.

**And code:**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Quote\Model\Quote;

class Item 
{
    public function afterSetProduct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject,
        $result
    ){
        $subject->setName('New Name');
    }
}
```

### Using Event & Observer Class

Defined an observer class `QuoteItemSetProduct.php` on the event `sales_quote_item_set_product`  from `app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/etc/events.xml`.

**Observer Class**

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Observer\Sales;

class QuoteItemSetProduct implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $quoteItem->setName('New Name');
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Amit. thanks for response. in your view is it better to use a plugin or to the event sales_quote_item_set_product. i read somewhere that magento is gradually moving away from using observers

Comment: Plugin is best for  now .As magento suggest to use plugin

Comment: To change the output Magento always recommend plugin. So better to use plugin only.

Comment: Hi again Amit.i will try your plugin solution tonight and then mark you as correct. not used plugins before so need to read up on it. thanks for that

Comment: hi @AmitBera could you please please help me with this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290812/magento-2-how-to-retrieve-custom-quote-params-from-quote-object-after-order

Comment: HI @AmitBera- just tested this and i am indeed able to change the product name. however, i need to get the name from my custom options. do u know how i can get it

Comment: @AmitBera - thanks . it works